# spinner dropdown show up on click of menu button

Tags: android

i want my spinner dropdown to show up on click of menu button in android.Like i press my menu button and on click of menu button my spinner dropdown shows up.can you please suggest a way ahead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call this on your menuItem click

```
Spinner.performClick();
```

Comment: Suppose i have that spinner in my action bar.Find the following code

ArrayAdapter<String> mSpinnerAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, arr);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, null);

then how to go for it?